# Git merging branch issue

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

When I try to merge dev branch to the master branch, I got the following error.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
test.py
Please move or remove them before you merge.
```

Does that mean I should manually remove the test.py file in the master branch before merging?
How should I handle it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `test.py` file exists on disk, but is not tracked in the branch you have currently checked out. If you merge from the source branch, which *does* track that file, the current file in the working folder, and its contents, will be lost, overwritten by the version from the source branch. Whether this is OK or if you want to keep the `test.py` file in your working folder, is something you have to decide.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably commit your changes in test.py before you merge

Comment: I did it already. I checked it via 'git status'. It shows working tree clean